# hide cell content if child spans are empty

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, hide, cell

There is a table 'OfficeInfo' with two rows with 2 cell each. Each cell will have Office info like name, address, phone and direction link. I need to hide the direction link (google map link based on the address value) or hide the whole cell if other info like name, addreses, phone etc are blank..lets say everything else is empty, hide the 'map and directions' link as well or the whole cell...How to do in Jquery?

```
<table class="OfficeInfo" border="0" style="width: 100%" cellspacing="10px" cellpadding="15px">
    <tr>
        <td class="Office1" style="width=40%">  
            <span class="OfficeName">
                Munster Women&#39;s Center<br />
            </span>
            <span class="Address">
                1111 North Ronald Reagan Pkwy,  <br />&#160;Avon,IN 46123      
            </span> 
            <span class="Phone">
                (317) 342-1254</span><br />
            <a class="mapdirectionsLink" href="#">map &#38; directions&#62;</a>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span class="Hours">
                MTW: 9:00 AM- 5:00 PM 
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="OfficeName">  </span>
            <span class="Address"></span>                                     
            <span class="Phone"></span>
            <br />
            <a class="mapdirectionsLink" href="#">map and directions</a>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span class="Hours"></span> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Office3
        </td>
        <td>
            Office4
        </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't include your final html it is tough to say. Always try and include what we will see on the page, not generic sharepoint calls.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ctjcv/7/

In this example I check whether each cell contains any children other than the map class. If not then we can safely hide it. You will see that cell1 shows the link because other data is present while cell 2 does not.

```
$('.OfficeInfo td').each( function() {
    if ($(this).children(':empty').not('.mapdirectionsLink, br').length > 0) {
        $(this).children('.mapdirectionsLink').hide();   
    }
});
```

Comment: Sure, easy addition. See my updated fiddle. You just add a :empty selector.

Comment: I thing you didn;t get what i meant..there wil be child elements no matter. There will be that link always showing up. Condition is if other elements in that cell are empty, then there is no need for that link to show up and hence has to be hidden..you can check for any span element whether it has text or not, if anyone of them don't, then its reason enough to hide the link. We can check for the OfficeName text being empty or not, if it is, we can hide the link since no office name, no link needed..

Comment: I think I see now. For each table cell, if any child element is empty, then hide the map link. Updated my answer and fiddle.

Comment: I really want to thank you so much for taking time to help me out here... i was banging my head on the wall..Updated solution worked like a charm...My guru for the day! Thank you thank you thank you!!

Comment: You are very welcome. I know how frustrating these things can get. When it seems you have tried everything, but nothing quite works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use text() method for that

```
$('.OfficeInfo tr td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).children().not('.mapdirectionsLink').text().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"") == '') {
        $(this).children('.mapdirectionsLink').hide();
    }
});
```

You can find [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XcFW5/)

There is an extra trim control..

**EDIT :** I just add some extra to mrtsherman's solution..

**EDIT 2 :** I changed function to hide all elements if there is no map info [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XcFW5/1/) 
 If you want to remove the elements (not hiding) you can change

```
$(this).children('*').hide();
```

line with:

```
$(this).children('*').remove();
```

Comment: What are you doing here? I thought OP wanted to hide the map link. Why are you replacing values in its sibling elements?

Comment: Question : I need to hide the direction link (google map link based on the address value) or hide the whole cell if other info like name, addreses, phone etc are blank. 
And, in updated HTML there are some blank span elements so i think this is the way of hiding all empty elements..

Comment: the link 'map and direction' is an empty link right now thats gonna be there no matter if other elements have values or not, so when other elements are empty, I wanna hide the link that way it doesn;t show up until other elements have values..if other elements have no values, it needs to go away..

Comment: In My Edit 2 you can see that, if there is an anchor element but all other spans are empty then, hide this anchor & span elements together (Just click Hide Button). But if you just want to hide anchor element you can see First JS Fiddle.